# Python 3 Conversion from bytes to string

Tags: string, python-3.x, python-2.7, byte, pyzmq

I have a code written in Python 2.7 that I need to convert in Python 3.6. In the code the zmq function recv_multipart outputs an array of bytes:

```
msg = b'\x80\x03csome_message'
```

that I need to convert to a string. If I do

```
 msg.decode()
```

I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It does not seem that zmq can directly output a string, so what can I do to convert the output to a string ?

Comment: The message is not a UTF-8-encoded string.  It looks like raw data bytes of some kind mixed with text.

Comment: Ok, how should I proceed it ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].  Why do you need a string? What is the exact expected output for your example? This looks more like a raw data structure that needs to be parsed, not blindly converted to a Unicode string.  If you *want* blind conversion, `msg.decode('latin1')` translates bytes 00h-FFh to Unicode codepoints U+0000 to U+00FF.